# Change font color of Dynamic Item In Text area Spotfire

Tags: html, fonts, colors, spotfire

I hope you can help. I am attempting to change the font color of a Dynamic Item in my Spotfire model. The Dynamic Item is located in a text area. See Pic 1

The current font color is black as you can see in Pic 1 the number 172931 is black I would like it to be white. I have entered the hex color code `color=#ffffff` into the HTML I believe correctly but when I save, the number remains black.

I have supplied the HTML code below, can the font color on this Dynamic Item be changed and if so can my HTML code be amended to make it white

Pic 1
[image]

CODE

```
    <P><FONT color=#ffffff face="Arial Narrow" size=4><STRONG>Customer Type</STRONG></FONT></P>
<P><FONT color=#ffffff><SpotfireControl id="6cb6f5f866a94194bd37cdaf185519d2" /></P>
<P><STRONG><FONT color=#ffffff face="Arial Narrow" size=4>Customer Count</FONT></STRONG></P>
<P><FONT color=#ffffff size=10><SpotfireControl id="2ce02c1cb83f4906b1fce2b03c22ba4a" /></P>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Philip Connell- Here are the steps:

- Edit HTML
- Select the spotfire control and click 'EDIT'
- Go to VALUES and set RULE to 'GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO' 0 which basically means all the values including 0.

This will save the font color of the control.

[image]

[image]

Note: Similar question asked in TIBCO Community forum. Here is the link.

https://community.tibco.com/questions/there-any-way-change-font-color-calculated-values-text-area-spotfire-7

Comment: Boo Yaaa!!!! Thank you so much ksp585 This worked perfectly. Once again thank you so much and much respect from Dublin it is greatly appreciated